# Get Sum(total) in Java from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I have one database - ***pro***. The table name is ***orders***. The table have one field - ***total***. The total have values - ***(100,200,300,400,500)***. Now I need to add all values from above database. How can I do this in Java? How can I write the query in Java? Please help me. This is my code part:

```
    public class GetCurrentDateTime {
     private Object sum;
    public int data(){  

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro","root","");

    PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select sum(total) from orders where status='Q' AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())");
     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
     println(result,getString(1));
    }

      catch(Exception exc){
      System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
      }
return 0;   
      }

    private void println(ResultSet result, Object string) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
      private Object getString(int i) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return sum;
    }
     }
```

This is my another class:

```
      public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    GetCurrentDateTime obj = new GetCurrentDateTime();
    System.out.println(obj.data());

    }

   }
```

If I have to run my demo class means the sum of total number is displayed on tomcat console window. But is it displayed null 0 only. How to call `sum(total)` function in Java? Please help me.

Comment: The SQL may work, but the code... It's basic java coding, but you are very far from the solution to see this in the Tomcat console. I suggest you to spend a few hours on reading some basic tutorial on java, jdbc and web programming. You may find many on the web.

Comment: Exactly the same question has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789551/sum-of-total-in-java), so I added the homework tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead your data method

```
public double data(){
  double value=0.0;
  try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro","root","");

     PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select sum(total) from orders where status='Q' AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())");
     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
     result.next();
     String sum = result.getString(1);
     System.out.println(sum);
     value = Double.parseDouble(sum);

    } catch(Exception exc){
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: i got this exception on my console window:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
 at com.xcart.GetCurrentDateTime.data(GetCurrentDateTime.java:34)
 at com.xcart.Demo.main(Demo.java:5)

Comment: what was the output before exception?

Comment: the output is display before exception is null o

Comment: try int sum = result.getInteger(1); instead of String sum = result.getString(1);

Comment: And the output before is still null or 0?

Comment: same exception only through.Before start of result set Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499) at com.xcart.GetMonthFromDate.data(GetMonthFromDate.java:30) at com.xcart.Demo.main(Demo.java:5)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14832/discussion-between-ice-and-krishnaveni)

Answer (score 2):

```
 println(result,getString(1));
```

should be with a point instead of comma like:

```
println(result.getString(1));
```

Comment: hi the output is displayed Before start of result set
0.why not getting total value

Comment: replace return 0 with return result.getstring(1). thenreplace data return type from int to string if you do not need is as int anywhere, and if you still get 0 try to run the SQL-Statement directly at the database to check if its running as you wish and what value it returns.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors to fix. An IDE such as Eclipse can help.

You should return the value retrieved from the resultSet with `result.getString(1)` not print it. You are returning 0 and that's why you see 0.

Your caller class shoud be a servlet if you want to see something in tomcat.

Try to fix something and yo'll be nearer to result.

Answer (score 0):

You must return result.getString(1) and not return 0 in the method data().

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like this it will work

```
        ...

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select sum(total) from orders where status='Q' AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        println(result.getString(sum(total)));
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
    return 0;   
}

private void println(ResultSet result, Object string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private Object getString(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sum;
}
```

You need to print or get the result of sum by specifying the sum(total) in the resultSet like `result.getString(sum(total))`.