# convert timestamp to date in java and display count value

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap, valueconverter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting timestamp to date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794648/converting-timestamp-to-date-in-java)

This is my database:

- Date         status
- 1343993311    Q
- 1343892452    C
- 1343892477    P

Here I have to check the query current date+status=Q information and get the count value.

This is my code:

```
public class TodayQ {
 public int data(){
int count=0;

//count++;

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro","root","");

    PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
     while(result.next()) {
            // Do something with the row returned.
            count++; //if the first col is a count.
        }



     }

      catch(Exception exc){
      System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
      }


    return count;
       }

        }
```

dis is my other class:

```
    public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
    TodayQ obj = new TodayQ();
    System.out.println(obj.data());

     }

     }
```

Here I have to edit the date is (yyyy-mm-dd) format.Now I got the output.but I wish to use timestamp on my database.so how is converted timestamp to date in java.How is use that code in my code.please help me.How is to do????

Comment: I wonder where this 'Order assignment' takes place? Related questions are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789551/sum-of-total-in-java#comment15664080_11789551) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790158/get-sumtotal-in-java-from-mysql-database#comment15663822_11790158). The whole class seems to be active on SO?!

Comment: Could it possibly be an assignment??

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following thing in your code

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date date = format.parse("1343993311");
```

Here `date` object will have `java.util.Date` objects reference. Means timestamp is converted into `Date` object.

Comment: i have to add above line after int count=0.that time i got following exceptions:Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1343455049"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
 at com.xcart.TodayQ.data(TodayQ.java:16)
 at com.xcart.Demo.main(Demo.java:8)